# Use the requests in python to request a url error？

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

Use the requests in python to request a url error
The code

```
import re
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
import time, datetime
import os

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


def get_random_proxy():
    proxypool_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/random'
    """
    get random proxy from proxypool
    :return: proxy
    """
    return requests.get(proxypool_url).text.strip()


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
    'Referer': 'http://www.nmpa.gov.cn/datasearch/home-index.html?79QlcAyHig6m=1636513393895',
    'Host': 'nmpa.gov.cn',
    'Origin': 'http://nmpa.gov.cn',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'close'
}
url = 'https://www.nmpa.gov.cn/datasearch/search-result.html'


def start_requests(coo):
    # r = json.loads(r.text)
    headers['Set-Cookie'] = coo
    s = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=(5, 5), verify=False)
    s.encoding = 'utf8'
    print(s.status_code)
    print(s)


while True:
    proxy = {'http': 'http://' + get_random_proxy(), 'https': 'https://' + get_random_proxy()}
    print(proxy)
    try:
        sess = requests.Session()
        sess.keep_alive = False  # 关闭多余连接
        res = sess.get(url='http://nmpa.gov.cn', headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}, proxies=proxy, timeout=10,
                       verify=False)
        res.close()
        print(res.status_code)
        res.encoding = 'utf8'
        cookie = res.headers['Set-Cookie']
        print(cookie)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            print(res.status_code)
            time.sleep(10)
            start_requests(cookie)
            break
    except Exception as error:
        time.sleep(10)
        print("没有连接成功", error)
```

> {'http': 'http://178.88.185.2:3128', 'https':
> 'https://58.27.253.211:8080'} 没有连接成功
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='178.88.185.2', port=3128): Max retries
> exceeded with url: http://nmpa.gov.cn/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot
> connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f061b693f70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))) {'http': 'http://103.130.242.218:63123',
> 'https': 'https://178.238.236.233:3128'} 没有连接成功
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='103.130.242.218', port=63123): Max retries
> exceeded with url: http://nmpa.gov.cn/ (Caused by
> ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f061b6c0130>, 'Connection to 103.130.242.218 timed out. (connect
> timeout=10)')) {'http': 'http://143.0.226.116:80', 'https':
> 'https://177.124.184.52:8080'} 没有连接成功
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='143.0.226.116', port=80): Max retries
> exceeded with url: http://nmpa.gov.cn/ (Caused by
> ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f061b693ca0>, 'Connection to 143.0.226.116 timed out. (connect
> timeout=10)'))

Comment: I am not clear what you want to achieve and what isn't working. Please can you provide this info via an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

although this is one year to answer, but here some hints or maybe answer for someone that might have same problem.

the main thing is to check if your proxy receive https, as an example if you are using burp as proxy to check your requests, burp receive only http, since it's localhost without any certification so it will be on http, so you have to tell your code that https go to http:/whatever .. example

```
proxy = {'http': 'http://' + get_random_proxy(), 'https': 'http://' + get_random_proxy()}
```

so now your https requests will be redirected to http path proxy, it will not affect the request itself (it will not downgrade the security when the request go to the requested website)